# Unable to generate JAXB artifacts due to WSDL import

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, wsdl, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am having a WSDL (lets say one.wsdl ) from which I want to generate JAXB artifacts using maven plugin. one.wsdl imports another wsdl (two.wsdl ) . When I am running the maven plugin to generate the JAXB artifacts , looks like its not recognizing two.wsdl and not generating the JAXB artifacts.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>DataBindings_XJC_generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl/</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>one.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generateDirectory>src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                <generatePackage></generatePackage>
                <readOnly>true</readOnly>
                <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <extension>false</extension>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <episode>false</episode>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`one.wsdl` is refering to `two.wsdl` like this (both are in same directory).

```xml
<wsdl:import namespace="http://namespce:uri" location="two.wsdl"/>
```

However If i give the `two.wsdl` (in the `include` tag) in plugin , its able to generate the jaxb artifacts successfully.

Can anyone please suggest what might have gone wrong with the plugin when it comes to recognizing the imported WSDL ?

Answer (score 1):

`maven-jaxb2-plugin` is just a wrapper for XJC. It does not do any schema processing on it own, it just calls XJC.

Please send me a test case as a PR request here:

https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests

I'll check if this has something to do with the plugin (unlikely) or forward it to Oracle.

I think, this might be also by design - if your `one.wsdl` does not use anything from `two.wsdl` then nothing for the `two.wsdl` will be generated.

Comment: Is there any solution? I have the same case, when `one.wsdl` has import of  `two.wsdl`. In case when I generate from `two.wsdl`, it throws exception - no xmlrootelement

Comment: @BSeitkazin Same answer. Send me a PR with a reproducing project here: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support